# Ubuntu can't see my 32GB ntfs thumb drive

Tags: ntfs

Nothing happens, when plugged. Blkid doesn't see it either. No luck with Disks as well.
It's like it isn't there at all.
The thumb drive shows up just fine under windows computers.
The ubuntu computer finds just fine other (smaller and fat16 drives)

So, is it the size, is it the file system or maybe the fact that ubuntu runs on macbook pro?

Comment: Can you post the output from `lsusb`

Comment: lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0245 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05ac:821a Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller

Answer (score 0):

The file system is only supported on Mac and PC. Ubuntu may or may or may not see it.  You may want to move the files off, format it to FAT and try again. Formatting usually does the trick, so even NTFS may work if you format it from a Mac or Ubuntu.

Comment: mm Ubuntu has ntfs-3g driver which reads and writes NTFS

Comment: Do you have the ntfs-3g installed?

Comment: Sometimes it does not work you should give it a shot.

Comment: yes i have the ntfs-3g installed and it works for other media in NTFS (ext hdd)

Unfortunately FAT on the flash drive is not an option because i need files over 4gb there

Comment: I had that happen to me recently before I re-installed Ubuntu and It appeared after the installation. Now I am confused. It may be a bug.